# Laravel Livewire dispatch() events not working

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have a Laravel Livewire web application. I want to show Products on a page and then -when a product is selected- go to the details page of that specific product.

I wanted to use dispatch() events but I can't get it to work properly.

I have two components:

- ShowProducts: will fetch all products from DB and pass it to the view (where I show them with `foreach`). When a product image is clicked, I will call a function `showProductDetail` that will dispatch an event
- ShowProductDetails: needs to capture the event and show details for the product

```
class ShowProducts extends Component{
            
  public $products;
  public $product;
        
  public function render() {
     $this->products= Product::all();
     return view('livewire.show-products');
  }
        
  public function showProductDetail($id) {
     $product = Product::find($id);
     $this->product = $product ;
        
      $this->dispatch('show-detail', id: $product->id)->to(ShowProductDetail::class);
   }
}
```

and

```
class showProductDetail extends Component {
  public $product;
    
  #[On('show-detail')]
  public function loadProduct($id)  {
      dd($id);
      $this->product = Product::find($id);
  }
    
  public function render() {
    return view('livewire.show-product-detail');
  }
}
```

Then in terms of the view (will just display all products):

```
# show-products.blade.php
  @foreach ($products as $product)
    <button type="button" wire:click="showProductDetail({{ $product->id }})">
      <img src="{{ $product->image}}">
     </button>
  @endforeach
```

and

```
# show-product-detail.blade.php
  <div>
    {{ $product->image}}
  </div>
```

In the developer tools, I can see that an event is emitted but the detail page does not load.

[image]

If not using dispatches, any other way I could make this navigation from Product to ProductDetail work?

Comment: Dispatch is for components on the current page. You probably want to redirect the user to the details page's route instead.